# Inconsistent horizontal spacing when using a new font in math mode

Tags: math-mode, fonts, spacing, fontspec

I am trying to work out a way of using the Optima font in both math mode and the main body of my text. The code I came up with is given below. It is by no means elegant, and if there is a better way, I'd be very grateful if someone could amend or reconstruct it. I would like to use the original computer modern font for symbols (sum, integral, etc.) and for Greek letters. In my output below, there is clearly an issue with horizontal spacing in math mode. For example, there is more space between a '1' and a neighbouring parenthesis than a '0'. There is also an issue with the spacing in the exponent '1-x', where the 'x' seems unusually close to the '-'. How can the above issues be amended to give a much more aesthetically pleasing output? 
[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.75cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{mathtools}  
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setmainfont[ItalicFont={Optima Italic}]{Optima}
\setmathfont{Optima}
\setsansfont{Optima}
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}

\begin{document}
\raggedbottom
The random variable $X$ is said to have a Bernoulli distribution if 
\begin{align*}
p_X(x)=p^{x}(1-p)^{1 - x}, \qquad x \in \lbrace 0,1\rbrace
\end{align*}
where $0 \leqslant p \leqslant 1$, so that if $X \sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(p)$, then $\mathrm{Pr}(X = 0)=1-p$ and $\mathrm{Pr}(X=1)=p$
\end{document}
```

Comment: `1` is narrower than `0` in terms of letterforms, so in a tabular figure setting, `1` will have more surrounding space than `0` and hence it appears farther to the surrounding parentheses. The problem with `1-x` is another issue: Optima is not designed as a math font so the spacing is inappropriate for math, and `mathspec` simply replaces math letters with text letters. You can try `1-"x` as described in the manual.

Comment: Is there a better way to have computer modern symbols (sum, int etc.) and Greek letters but use Optima as the italic and regular math font?

Comment: Maybe try with the `mathastext` package?